# mySQL LIKE Query on Full Text

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search, sql-like, full-text-indexing

I'm trying to search for city names in a table with a few million rows.

I'm not really trying to do a fulltext search, but something close. For instance searching for "Los Ang" should not just return "Los Angeles", but also "East Los Angeles" - but not "EastLos Angeles" (white space!).

Unfortunately, this would require a query somewhat like this:

```
SELECT 
    cities.name
FROM
    cities
WHERE
    (cities.name LIKE '% los angel%' OR cities.name LIKE 'los angel%') AND cities.country = 'US'
LIMIT 40
```

This would return my expected results - but it takes about 6 seconds, which is bad. Removing the LIKE '% los angel%' clause will improve the query to 0.05 seconds or so, but not giving me the full results I am looking for.

Index wise there is a B-TREE Index on column cities.name (varchar 200). Can't do fulltext Index, because it's a innodb table.

Any smart way I could optimize this without converting to myisam?

I do not care so much about writing performance, as it's mostly a read-only table.

Comment: If you use %text mysql cant use the index. 
InnoDB supports fulltext index in version > 5.6.4

Comment: I'm aware that %text indexation is not possible. Hence I'm looking for other more or less elegant ways to address this. I'm still running on mysql 5.5.x at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No MySQL indexing method will get you "East Los Angeles" but not "EastLos Angeles", plus the many unstated cases: "Dayton" but not "Daytona Beach", "Forest Hill" but not "Forest Hills", "Portland, ME" but not "Portland, OR".  Etc.

You may, however, use a combination of SQL and application code.  Searching for "Angeles" using a `FULLTEXT` index will be very fast, then the application code can deal with what comes around it.  Note that "Hill" may match "Hills" in `FULLTEXT`, so that would be another thing to check.  Also, there is a minimum "word length"; if you don't change that, the "Fe" in "Santa Fe Springs" will be ignored.  And short names ("Roy", in Utah) could be an issue.  Norway has a 1-letter city:  "Å".

Comment: I eventually upgraded my MySQL version to 5.6.x in order to support Fulltext Indexation with InnoDB. Then I solved the minimum word length and the stopword table issues - like you mentioned there are on or two letter cities in the world, and also some cities contain words from the stopwords table. So overall, your answer reflects more or less what I have done, which gives me great satisfaction :)